# PHP/PDO: use simple prepared statement with query return/affected rows?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am new to PDO objects and cannot find a single piece of documentation that will help me. Say I got a simple code to delete a row:

```
$count = $dbh->exec("DELETE FROM fruit WHERE colour = 'red'");
```

That will return affected rows, but how would I use prepared statements with that? Can use use `$dbh->prepare` AND `$dbh->exec` or query !?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should be the same as any other statement:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM fruit WHERE colour = ?");
$stmt->execute(array('red'));
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
```

The [PDO Statement rowCount()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) should be what you are looking to do.

**EDIT**

Fixed by adding the `->rowCount()` which will return the row count. `->execute` in a statement will return a `bool`, `true` or `false` whether the query errored out or not. Of course all of this information is readily available at the [PDO Statement Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php)

Comment: So `->execute` can return affected rows too, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: No, I had an error before. The manual states that `->execute` returns a bool, but looking at the other functions in the manual, `->rowCount()` will provide the count.

Comment: This would fit my code perfectly, and makes a lot more sense with the `->rowCount()` function in the end. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

`$dbh->prepare` returns a `PDOStatement` object. You then call `$stmt->execute` to get the result.

[More info in the PDO manual](http://php.net/pdo)

Here's an example from the manual:

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of insert values */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
                       FROM fruit
                       WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$stmt->execute(array($calories, $colour));
?>
```

Comment: But how would I return number of rows affected? Can I use it like in my example, `$count = $stmt->execute`? EDIT: someone else answered it.