# Prevent SQL injection with regular expression?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to prevent SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

I wanted to ask you do i need to use something else from the code bellow:

```
         if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
         $username = $_POST['username'];
         $password = $_POST['password'];
         $validate = '/^[a-z]+[a-z0-9]*[.-_]*$/i';
               if ((preg_match($validate , $username)==true) && (preg_match($validate ,                                                                                     $password)==true)) {

                        some query...   
               } else {
                        echo "You've used some characters that aren't allowed.";
               }
       }else {
               echo 'Not logged!';  
       }
```

Is this regular expression good to save me from SQL injection?Or can you give me any other suggestions to make my login form good enought!

Comment: It is. But if you want to be lazy, then rather eschew cumbersome database [escaping completely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659898/php-pdo-use-simple-prepared-statement-with-query-return-affected-rows).

Answer (score 3):

use `mysql_real_escape_string` if your driver is still the older one, or prepared statements with parameters binding if you are using newer pdo drivers, or `mysqli_real_escape_string` from mysqli.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: And what about wrong sql queries to the databse? Even with the prepared statements they will be send that isn't good for server productivity.